# Tensorflow slim pre-trained alexnet

Tags: python, tensorflow, tf-slim

The Tensorflow slim library provides the graph structure for alexnet, however it doesn't seem to provide a pre-trained (on Imagenet) alexnet checkpoint (https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/research/slim). Is there anywhere a pre-trained alexnet checkpoint for TF-slim is provided?

Comment: I'm searching for this as well... did you ever find an alexnet checkpoint @h1234s?

Comment: Me as well. Here's a vanilla TF one:  https://github.com/guerzh/tf_weights

Answer (score 3):

Unlike VGG or Inception, TensorFlow doesn’t ship with a pretrained AlexNet.
Caffe does but it's not a trivial task to convert to tensorflow.

Thanks to [Frederik Kratzert](https://kratzert.github.io/aboutme), he did that job and share [here](https://kratzert.github.io/2017/02/24/finetuning-alexnet-with-tensorflow.html)

In summary, you need to:

1. Download [Caffe model and weights](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/tree/master/models/bvlc_alexnet)
2. Use the [caffe-to-tensorflow](https://github.com/ethereon/caffe-tensorflow) to convert the Caffe model to Tensorflow model
3. Refer the diferences if any between the converted model and the slim model and make the adaptation

For more details, please look [here](http://www.cs.toronto.edu/~guerzhoy/tf_alexnet/)